# What's the adjectival form of 'deficit'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Does *deficit* have an adjectival form? If my business loses a lot of money, can I say that I 'got a deficit', that my business is 'in a deficit', or that my business suffered 'a deficit'?

Is there a common way to express the concept of *deficit* adjectivally?

Comment: The adjectival form for *deficit* is *deficient,* but it doesn't mean what you want it to.

Comment: The word *deficit* comes from the French *déficit* but unfortunately only the noun was imported. In French it would be *déficitaire*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by *deficit* you mean your expenses are greater than your income (or your liabilities are growing faster than your assets), I would say your business is **loss-making**,  **unprofitable**, or **profitless** (among adjectives).

If it continues to lose money, it will be ultimately be **unsuccessful**, because the success of a business is measured by its profits.

I do not believe *deficit*, at least in the financial sense, has a common adjective form. In speaking of government spending deficits, for example, we usually hear compounds such as *deficit-related* or *deficit-oriented*.

Comment: In my opinion "unprofitable" means not earn money, but not lose money either. So i want to use "deficit" to express the situation

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Shor comments, the standard adjectival form for *deficit* is *deficient*. But OP may be thinking of...

> My business is **in deficit**. *(no 'a')*

...which a [quick check](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22business%20is%20in%20deficit%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22business%20is%20in%20deficit%22&oq=%22business%20is%20in%20deficit%22&gs_l=serp.3...3232.5650.0.6353.9.9.0.0.0.0.108.533.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.LodQE7ol3iI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=644001cab0275ea4&biw=1300&bih=905) on Google Books reveals to be less common than I'd expected. Lots of other things can [be in deficit](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22business%20is%20in%20deficit%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22is%20in%20deficit%22&oq=%22is%20in%20deficit%22&gs_l=serp.3...109771.111313.2.111777.9.9.0.0.0.0.84.518.9.9.0...0.0...1c.04RhmmMmOb8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=644001cab0275ea4&biw=1300&bih=905), but apparently they're mostly budgets, accounts, and balances.

I have no problem with *"My business is in deficit"* meaning *"My business is losing/has lost money"*, *"...is trading in the red"*, *"...is running at a loss"*, etc. Luckily, I'm not a businessman!

Answer (score 0):

I believe ***deficient*** may well be the correct term.  When a business is in ***deficit*** (without further explanation), that specifically refers to *profits*. If I am in ***deficit***, my profits are ***deficient***.